# How to show editor in custom category attribute in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I added one custom category attribute by taking the help of this link

```
http://www.atwix.com/magento/add-category-attribute/
```

But it showing only the textarea not the editor.can anybody tell me where i doing mistake or anything i left.

In
app/etc/modules/Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/community/Atwix/CustomCategoryAttribute/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <resources>
            <add_category_attribute>
                <setup>
                    <module>Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute</module>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </add_category_attribute>
            <add_category_attribute_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </add_category_attribute_write>
            <add_category_attribute_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </add_category_attribute_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/code/community/Atwix/CustomCategoryAttribute/sql/add_category_attribute/mysql4-upgrade-0.0.1-0.0.2.php

```
<?php
$this->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'custom_attribute', array(
    'group'         => 'General',
    'input'         => 'textarea',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'label'         => 'Custom attribute',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
));

$this->endSetup();
```

For showing

app/design/frontend/theme/template/catalog/category/view.phtml

```
<?php if($_customAttribute = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getCustomAttribute()): ?>
    <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_customAttribute, 'custom_attribute') ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If anyone knows this,please help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: Price ,you want enable editor for textarea field??

Comment: yes, but i don't know how to do it?

Comment: @PrinceKumar a screenshot from you may help

Comment: same code i have used as it is given in link above please refer and tell me how to show editor

Comment: What is your version number in `config.xml` and your setup script upgrade version ?

Comment: I am using the magento 1.8.0.1.But i have written the same version that is written there.i.e.,<version>0.0.1</version>

Comment: please see the code above i used.

Comment: There is also `mysql4-upgrade-0.0.1-0.0.2.php` script which enables `WYSIWYG` editor. `0.0.2` should be in your config.xml file

Comment: please see above i wrote all the codes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58145/discussion-between-prince-kumar-and-slimshadddyyy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your upgrade script `mysql4-upgrade-0.0.1-0.0.2.php` will contain the following code

```
<?php
$this->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'custom_attribute', array(
    'group'         => 'General',
    'input'         => 'textarea',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'label'         => 'Custom attribute',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
));

$this->endSetup();
```

In your `config.xml` change the version to below

`<modules>
        <Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute>
            <version>0.0.2</version>
        </Atwix_CustomCategoryAttribute>
</modules>`

You can see the property `'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,`

It is necessary to use editor to change the content in this attribute, insert some image, format text and at the end – to save the changes

Comment: can you plz tell me how i know that it is which version 0.0.1 or 0.0.2?

Comment: In your DB, under `core_resource` table, search your module name in `code` field and its corresponding `version`

Answer (score 0):

create own mysql upgrade script....mysql4-upgrade-0.0.1-0.0.2.php
Here,code of this file is

```
$installer =new Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup;
$categoryEntityTypeId = $installer->getEntityTypeId('catalog_category');

$installer->updateAttribute($categoryEntityTypeId, 'custom_attribute', 'is_wysiwyg_enabled', 1);

$installer->endSetup();
```

Which will update your category attribute.